# Open specific activity when notification is tapped in FCM

Tags: android, push-notification

I am getting push notifications when app is in background/foreground/killed state but when the notification is tapped, the following thing happens,

- Activity is **opened** when notification is tapped when app is in
  foreground/background
- Activity is **not opened** when the app is **killed**

The code doesn't work in any devices(Chinese and non Chinese devices and Oreo and below Oreo devices). I have checked all duplicate answers in SO but nothing works.

What am I missing here? Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

I have the following code in php script

```
$msg = array
(
  'body' => $_REQUEST['message'],
  'title' => $_REQUEST['title'],
  'click_action' =>  ('.Activity.SplashActivity'), 
 );

 $fields = array
 (
     'to' => $_REQUEST['token'],
     'notification' => $msg ,
     'data'=>$msg,

);
```

The following code is in AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
  <activity android:name=".Activity.SplashActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASHACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The following is the notification code,

```
 private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.e("remoteMessage foreground", remoteMessage.getData().toString());
    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , IntroSplashActivity.class);
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
            0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.account_icon))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.account_icon)
            .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
            .setNumber(10)
            .setTicker("Bestmarts")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentInfo("Info");
    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: You need to send [Data messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Comment: @ADM I am sending in php script. That's what you mean right?

Comment: Yeah .. you seems to currently sending notification messages this is why FCM is handled it for you and this code of your never gets called when app is killed . Send Data messages instead .

Comment: @ADM please check my post once again. I have clearly mentioned I am getting notification in all the 3 states and I am sending data messages too in the php script.